# PHP Function for evaluating percentage change

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a function which evaluates two numbers and sees if there is a percentage change that happens.

```
// $live_data = data pulled from an API - ex: .000121231 or 2500.00
// $pervious_data = data pulled from a DB - ex: .0001231 or 11111.00
// $alert_data['value'] = data pulled from a DB - ex: 10 or -10

function percent_change_eval($data, $alert_data, $previous, $currency){
  $live_data = (float)$data[$currency][$alert_data['comparison']];
  $previous_data = (float)$previous[$alert_data['comparison']];
  $percent = round((($live_data) - ($previous_data)) / ($previous_data) * 100, 10);
  switch($alert_data['operator']) {     
    case ">=":
        if($percent > $alert_data['value']){
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
        break 1;
    case "<=":
        if($percent < $alert_data['value']){
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
        break 1;
  }
}
```

I've built the function but for some reason it keeps throwing `true` when it shouldn't. I'm assuming it has something to do with the numbers being either too big or too small or if one of the vars is null.

Any advice or help?

Comment: What is the value for `$alert_data['operator']` first time and second time? Also, try to use string in the switch case instead of operators('<=', '>=').

Comment: My advice is to log the values of $percent, $alert_data['operator'] and $alert_data['value'] just before the switch statement. Just to make sure that the TRUEs aren't caused by the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer per se, but I hate `switch` cases. It took 16 lines of code!

I'd rewrite it using just two lines:

```
if($alert_data['operator'] == '>=') return $percent > $alert_data['value']);
if($alert_data['operator'] == '<=') return $percent < $alert_data['value']);
```

Looks cleaner and much less place for making a mistake